# SQL query left join where clause

Tags: mysql, sql, join

This is my situation.

I have 3 tables

```
Orders
 - id  status deleted

Order Lines
 - related_id related_model quantity

Products
 - id  code  price  price_purchase
```

I want to create a list with `all products`. The `amount of times they are purchased` and a `sum of the gross margin` (price - price_purchase). It must only use orders lines with the `related model set to 'products'`. And secondly it must only pick orders with the `status set to 'paid, processing, sent, ready_for_pickup or picked_up'` and with the order `not deleted.`

So this would be the result I want:

```
id | code  | purchases | value
-------------------------------
1  | code1 | 7         | 57,05
2  | code2 | 122       | 254,98
3  | code3 | 0         | 0,00
```

This is the SQL query I have so far:

```
SELECT p.id, p.code, IFNULL(SUM(sol.quantity) , 0) as purcahses,     
sum((p.price - p.price_purchase) * quantity) as value
FROM products p
LEFT JOIN shop_orders_lines sol ON sol.related_id = p.id 
AND sol.related_model = 'products'
LEFT JOIN shop_orders so ON so.id = sol.order_id 

WHERE so.status IN ('paid', 'processing', 'sent', 'ready_for_pickup', 'picked_up')
AND so.deleted = 0  
GROUP BY p.id
```

It returns the correct data. But not all problems. That is my problem. I a lot of different methods like sub queries and other methods but can't seem to solve the problem. I know the problem is my LEFT join, but don't know a solution to my problem.

I'm using MySQL Workbench.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: Aside: the `related_model` column indicates that your schema violates [the principle of orthogonal design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_orthogonal_design).

Comment: Your description of what you want is incongruent with the rest of what you are saying. You want *all* products? Or ones filtered down? Do they need to have an order for them to be returned? Do they need to be a part of an order line to be returned? Please restate your desired output in very clear terms so somebody can help you

Comment: Tim, My description is pretty clear. So I want all products with their gross margin and amount of purchases. So if they haven't been bought before there is probably not an order line for it. So it should show a 0 in the last 2 columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your joins are wrong.  You need to identify the order lines to consider separately from and prior to forming the LEFT JOIN with the product details.  An inline view could help:

```
  SELECT
    p.id,
    p.code,
    IFNULL(SUM(ordered_item.quantity) , 0) as purchases ,     
    sum((p.price - p.price_purchase) * ordered_item.quantity) as value
  FROM
   products p
   LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT
        sol.related_id AS related_id,
        sol.quantity AS quantity
      FROM
        shop_orders_lines sol
        INNER JOIN shop_orders so
          ON so.id = sol.order_id
      WHERE
        so.status IN ('paid', 'processing', 'sent', 'ready_for_pickup', 'picked_up')
          AND so.deleted = 0
          AND sol.related_model = 'products'  
    ) ordered_item
      ON ordered_item.related_id = p.id
GROUP BY p.id
```

Answer (score 1):

Move outer table conditions from WHERE to ON, otherwise the OUTER JOIN works like a regular INNER JOIN:

```
SELECT p.id, p.code, IFNULL(SUM(sol.quantity) , 0) as purcahses,     
sum((p.price - p.price_purchase) * quantity) as value
FROM products p
LEFT JOIN shop_orders_lines sol ON sol.related_id = p.id 
AND sol.related_model = 'products'
LEFT JOIN shop_orders so ON so.id = sol.order_id AND
so.status IN ('paid', 'processing', 'sent', 'ready_for_pickup', 'picked_up')
AND so.deleted = 0
GROUP BY p.id
```

Is p.id the whole primary key for that table? If not, you need to find out how to treat p.code. (Either list in GROUP BY, or use as argument to aggregate function.)

**Another try:**

```
SELECT p.id, p.code, IFNULL(SUM(sol.quantity) , 0) as purcahses,     
sum((p.price - p.price_purchase) * quantity) as value
FROM products p
JOIN shop_orders_lines sol ON sol.related_id = p.id 
AND sol.related_model = 'products'
WHERE EXISTS (select 1 from shop_orders so
              where so.id = sol.order_id
                AND so.status IN ('paid', 'processing', 'sent', 'ready_for_pickup', 'picked_up')
                AND so.deleted = 0)
GROUP BY p.id
```

Comment: It isn't working. It returns to many purchases. It is returning all purchases and it is ignoring the status. And yes, p.id is the primary key for products

Comment: What's the purpose of the second LEFT JOIN? Can't you move that logic/condition to an EXISTS?

Comment: Your edit is working. Only problem now, it doesn't return all products. To come back to your question. The 2nd join is needed to see the status of the order. Since items in a cart are placed as a order line for some reason.